# Does Poco C++ library have a cross platform WaitForMultipleObjects() analog?

Tags: c++, events, cross-platform, poco-libraries, waitformultipleobjects

Based on [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2664913/is-there-a-c-cross-platform-named-event-like-the-createevent-in-win32) I am going to use Poco::NamedEvent, but I need to wait for multiple events (like win32 WaitForMultipleObjects()

Is there such a thing in poco?  (searching the docs doesn't yield much but perhaps I am not using the right searches)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you'll find WaitForMultipleObjects() in any cross-platform package, including Poco.  No Unix variant of which I am aware packages that kind of functionality in single API call but rather spreads it out depending on the kind of object you are waiting on.

Comment: they would all be the same class of object - in this case a NamedEvent.

Comment: @Tim You have probably looked already but NamedEvent is just a wrapper around CreateEvent or a semaphore depending on the platform. Not sure what you are doing but I don't see an easy way around this without coding your own clever hack.

Comment: Yeah - I grepped the source for waitformultipleobjects.  I'll just start a thread for each event and wait on it.  Not sure that is the best solution but it will work...

Answer (score 0):

class NotificationQueue would let you queue up objects, and process them. It is better OOP to use IOC and delegates than to have a big WaitForMultipleObjects followed by a switch statement, anyways.

Comment: Are you saying NotificationQueue works across processes? (http://pocoproject.org/docs/Poco.NotificationQueue.html)

Comment: Despite popular belief, "better OOP" doesn't always trump "does what I need".

Comment: @jalf - I couldn't agree more.  A switch statement with 5 entries that calls a method for each one (an event handler) is no different than delegates.  It is also simple to read and easy to maintain.