# Waiting on condition variable

Tags: multithreading, synchronization, condition-variable

I found this on SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/178114/pthread-like-windows-manual-reset-event):

```
void mrevent_wait(struct mrevent *ev) {
    pthread_mutex_lock(&ev->mutex);
    while (!ev->triggered)
         pthread_cond_wait(&ev->cond, &ev->mutex);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&ev->mutex);
}
```

The manpage sais:

> The pthread_cond_wait() and pthread_cond_timedwait() functions are used to block on a condition variable. They are called with mutex locked by the calling thread or undefined behaviour will result.
>
> These functions atomically release mutex and cause the calling thread to block on the condition variable cond;

Then shouldn't the mutex be captured before each call to `pthread_cond_wait`. Also, why is the mutex unlocked when the manpage sais that pthread_cond_wait do that for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're reading the documentation slightly wrong. What it is saying is that, within the call to `pthread_cond_wait()`, the mutex is unlocked (which is required, or otherwise the `pthread_cond_signal()` or `pthread_cond_broadcast()` would never be able to trigger the condition variable). After the condition variable has been triggered, the mutex will be re-locked before `pthread_cond_wait()` returns. That is the reason that you must then unlock it again.

Because `pthread_cond_wait()` needs to re-acquire the mutex before returning to you, there is the possibility that a different thread may get the mutex first, which means that by the time `pthread_cond_wait()` returns to you, the condition you are waiting on may have already passed, which is why you must test the condition in the `while` loop.