# Equivalence of WaitForSingleObject() & ResetEvent() in Linux

Tags: c, linux, windows, multithreading

I'm trying to translate some code written using windows functions for a Linux environment and I couldn't figure out what the equivalence of these are in Linux. My understanding of `WaitForSingleObject` is that it waits for a flag and at the end of the function, `ResetEvent` resets that flag.

The piece of code I'm working with is written as follows:

```
HANDLE someEvent;
WaitForSingleObject(someEvent, INFINITE);
{ some code }
ResetEvent(someEvent);
```

Comment: Have you tried to google? This one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33098419/linux-posix-equivalent-for-win32s-createevent-setevent-waitforsingleobject. Or that one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2719580/waitforsingleobject-and-waitformultipleobjects-equivalent-in-linux. And [others](https://www.google.ru/search?q=WaitForSingleObject+Linux+site:stackoverflow.com)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WaitForSingleObject and WaitForMultipleObjects equivalent in Linux](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2719580/608639) and [Porting windows manual-reset event to Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/178114/608639)

Comment: @Tsyvarev yes obviously I would google before posting on here so someone like you wouldn't tell me to go google it... those answers were vague and didn't help that's why i asked again

Comment: But what is "vague" in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33099359/3440745)? Or in some other ones? If you want some clarification, ask exactly what answer is unclear, and what exactly is unclear in it.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for pthread_cond_wait

Here's [a link](https://gist.github.com/alexklibisz/7cffdfe90c97986f8393) to a simple usage. You will see how both sides of the communication work.

Andres